# Java: Cast on Iterator ignore integer except String type

Tags: java, string, iterator, integer, classcastexception

Can somebody explain to me the reason why Java ignores the cast for the iterator on all object types except the `String` class?

I have the following code:

```
List list = new LinkedList();
list.add(new Object());
list.add(new String("First"));
list.add(10);
list.add(2.3);
```

I have two cases:

1)

```
Iterator<Integer> crunchifyIterator = list.iterator();
while (crunchifyIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println((crunchifyIterator.next()));
}
```

The result is:

> java.lang.Object@2a139a55
>   First
>   10
>   2.3

2)

```
Iterator<String> crunchifyIterator = list.iterator();
while (crunchifyIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println((crunchifyIterator.next()));
}
```

The result is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String

I don't know what the reason is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple versions of `System.out.println()`

You are adding different types of `Objects` to the list

```
List list = new LinkedList();
list.add(new Object()); // Type Object
list.add(new String("First")); // Type String
list.add(10);  // Type Integer (not int)
list.add(2.3); // Type Float (not float)
```

In the fist loop it calls

```
System.out.println(Object o);  // String, Interger, Float are all objects this causes no issues
```

In the second loop it calls

```
System.out.println(String str);  // This is where the casting fails, Object, Integer, and Float are not Strings.
```

The reason for this is in operator overloading the version called is determined at compile time (not runtime).

**Note:**

In practice you should not be using a generic type on your iterator other then the generic type of your List. In your case the type defaults to Object.

Comment: Hi cyroxis, but if I write this `Iterator<Integer> crunchifyIterator = list.iterator();` is permited and if I try  whit that `Iterator<String> crunchifyIterator = list.iterator();` throws a exception

Comment: @Abelo I updated my answer to give some more clarity.